# Using pcregrep for multiple files

Tags: regex

I am trying to use pcregrep multiline match on a set of files. And those files itself are coming out some searches from the current directory, something like below:

```
l | grep -P "\d\.mt.+" | cut -d":" -f 2 | cut -d" " -f 2 | xargs
```

So, I want to do a pcregrep on these set of files, and that is a multiline match, as below:

```
pcregrep -Mi "index(.+\n)+" list of files
```

I don't know, if it's possible to give the list of file names like this.

Can someone help?

Regards,
Manu

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
l | grep -P "\d\.mt.+" | cut -d":" -f 2 | cut -d" " -f 2 | xargs pcregrep -Mi "index(.+\n)+"
```

Your command provides `xargs` at the end but with no command to use it.

Now, xargs is useful and the command is just like

```
pcregrep <*list of all found files*>
```

That's the idea behind xargs.